# cpptask ordering of static libraries in gcc command line

Tags: c++, c, ant

How do I force cpptask to move the static libraries to the end on arg list issued to the compiler?

Here is the clause I am using

```
   <cpptasks:cc description="appname" subsystem="console" objdir="obj" outfile="dist/app_test">
            <compiler refid="testsslcc" />      
            <linkerarg value="-L${libdir}" />   
            <linkerarg value="-L/usr/local/devl/lib" />
            <linkerarg value="-Wl,-rpath,../lib" />
            <libset libs="unittest ${libs} dsg readline ncurses gcov" />
            <fileset dir="test/obj" includes="main.o" />
            <fileset dir="." includes="${TCFILES}" />
            <fileset dir="../lib" includes="libboost_thread.a libboost_date_time.a" />                                                     
    </cpptasks:cc>
```

when this executes, libboost_thread.a libboost_date_time.a  are first files in the argument list passed the compiler,

```
gcc -ggdb -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wshadow -Wno-format-y2k  \
    ../../lib/libboost_date_time.a ../../lib/libboost_thread.a x.cpp ...
```

which causes compiler error. By manually moving them to the end of the argument list, the application compiles without error.

```
gcc -ggdb -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wshadow -Wno-format-y2k x.cpp ... \
    ../../lib/libboost_date_time.a ../../lib/libboost_thread.a
```

And yes I have tried changing the order in the xml, and that of course didn't work. For now I am using an exec task to call gcc with the files in the correct order but this of course is a hack.

Comment: How did get the gcc command line generated by Ant?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `fileset` with the archives into `libset`.